# eth_getLogs only returns logs for last transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, events, logs

The following command only returns logs for the last transaction (or block). I'm currently running `ganach-cli` for the local testnet.

There were previous transactions with events but when a new transaction with an event is created, then only the events for the last transaction show.

```
curl http://172.17.0.2:8545 -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"address": "0x624f622c59f8daa47f3f7415c4e81e6fff6b6373", "topics":[]}],"id":6}'

{"id":6,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"logIndex":"0x00","transactionIndex":"0x00","transactionHash":"0x73bf34a131d6dfb801d55bb03928d6c2396751c932da75ca6759e539b8a0b9e9","blockHash":"0x201fdc0501219545ec3e797cf48ec7e898b65a7ef0fc4ae1500f492e06c33b19","blockNumber":"0x0a","address":"0x624f622c59f8daa47f3f7415c4e81e6fff6b6373","data":"0x0000000000000000000000008a2e9ba3b4a8805bd6f028ee12e28e8995e654fb00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004064976a8dd00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000214e8348c4f0000","topics":["0x57bad7e3c9efecf6e1f60bbd846b999e9da4a409224287a8df09779f2330135e","0x0000000000000000000000008a2e9ba3b4a8805bd6f028ee12e28e8995e654fb"],"type":"mined"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying `fromBlock`, hence "latest" is used as default value. If you want all events, you'll have to pass as filter parameter `fromBlock:0`.